# 3D construction from set of 2D images using mobile camera

Tags: image, volume, point-clouds, photogrammetry, 2d-3d-conversion

I need to detect the 3D point cloud of the object from the 2D photographs I took with my smartphone camera. I'm going to estimate the volume of fast food.I attempted to develop certain computer vision toolboxes in Matlab, but failed.